# XeLatex does not compile

Tags: xetex, compiling, texstudio

I am using for the first time XeLatex on Ubuntu 16.04, via TexStudio, but I cannot compile anything. I don't even get a log file with errors, but just the message

Error: One command expansion invalid.
    Parent Command: compile
    Primary Command: compile

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How did you install TeX? As `texlive` from the repos? Do you even have xelatex?

Comment: Do LaTeX or pdfLaTeX work or is the problem specific to XeLaTeX?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
@TeXnician PdfLatex works fine.

Comment: Type `xelatex` in a terminal. What's the output?

Comment: @jjdb I think I installed (long time ago) it via texlive. How do I check if I have xelatex? I thought it was already included in what I have

Comment: Ok it says it is not not installed. Now I try to install it.

Comment: If you've installed it a long time ago, it would be best to install the current version of texlive anyway. Best install it via the install script as the Ubuntu repositories are usually not up-to-date, see this answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/28751 In the install script you can then choose what to install.

Comment: Ok in the end I just installed it via sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex and it works fine! Thanks! Should I answer the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an incomplete software installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end xelatex was not installed. 
I installed it via

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```